# Utilizando o comando php artisan make:repository

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.2

Olá, gostaria de tirar uma dúvida.
Estou utilizando o comando:

```
php artisan make:repository ProjectNote
```

E gostaria de saber como faço para o comando entender que eu quero que minha migrate tenha o nome

```
create_table_project_notes
```

E consequentemente minha tabela tenha o nome

```
project_notes
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Não entendo muito de artesian, mas pelo pouco que li na documentação acho que seria `php artisan make:migration NOME_DO_MIGRATION --table=NOME_DA_TABELA`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acho que ele vai ter que usar uma library que faça isso no Laravel. Por padrão, ele só cria o esqueleto das classes, não insere funcionalidades como nomes de tabelas e afins

Comment: Está usando este package? https://github.com/andersao/laravel-repository

Answer (score 3):

Anderson o comando este correto.
 
`php artisan make:repository ProjectNote`, com esse comando você terá o resultado abaixo.

Migration
`2016_07_10_225826_create_project_notes_table.php`

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('project_notes', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```